# Use beforeunload only on tab close

Tags: javascript

below code will trigger a popup with **Reload site?** or **Leave site?** message
on **page refresh**, **press back button** or on **tab close**

How to trigger this event only on **tab close**

```js
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
   // Cancel the event
   e.preventDefault();
   // Chrome requires returnValue to be set
   e.returnValue = '';
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way of doing it because javascript doesen't have access to read browser actions. But if you want to do something on the server based on these actions, you may find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568977/identifying-between-refresh-and-close-browser-actions) helpful.