# Onbeforeunload don't prompt confirmation for page reload

Tags: javascript, html

I'm adding an event listener for [`onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event) that prompts a confirmation message when the user tries to leave the page.

Unfortunately, I don't want the confirmation message to appear when the user tries to reload the page.

How do I do this?

Here's what I have so far:

```js
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return "";
}
```

Comment: `onbeforeunload` even runs before leaving the site, closing the tab, and refreshing the page. I don't think the browser distinguishes between them

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568977/identifying-between-refresh-and-close-browser-actions may help

Comment: You may wanna look at this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigationTiming/type And try to storage data, like timestamp in local storage for comparaison

Answer (score 2):

It's completely possible<sup>1</sup>.

You can listen for the `keydown` event and check whether the user reloaded the page via the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>. If so, you can set a variable (in our case, `isReload`) to `true` and set a timeout to set it back to false after, say, 100 milliseconds.

When the `onbeforeunload` event fires, check whether `isReload` is `true`. If it is, return `null` to allow the browser to close. Otherwise, return `""` to prompt a confirmation.

Demo:

```js
var isReload = false;
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
    if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 82){
        isReload = true;
        setTimeout(function(){isReload = false}, 100);
    }
})
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    if(!isReload){
        return "";
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}
```

<sup><sup>1</sup> This only works for the shortcut. You can't differentiate between closure/reload if the user manually clicks the reload button</sup>