# How to prevent calling onbeforeunload when page refresh?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I am working on React Js Application, I am using Localstorage for managing the Application Token. And i want, when user close the TAB, localsotorage will get empty. For that i am using beforeunload.

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", () => localStorage.clear());
```

But this things also call when i refresh the browser. I want to prevent it, that when user refresh the browser, localstorage not clear. How can i achive it?

I can not want to use **sessionStorage** because i need to communicate token/record with other tabs as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Identifying Between Refresh And Close Browser Actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568977/identifying-between-refresh-and-close-browser-actions)

Comment: Why not just use [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) instead of localStorage? It is automatically deleted when the session ends (but would remain through a refresh)

Comment: @Justinas I have not get exact thing what i want. Have you any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [PerformanceNavigationTiming.type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigationTiming/type) to

**check if page gets reloaded or refreshed in JavaScript**

```
const pageAccessedByReload = (
   (window.performance.navigation && window.performance.navigation.type === 1) ||
    window.performance
       .getEntriesByType('navigation')
       .map((nav) => nav.type)
       .includes('reload')
);

alert(pageAccessedByReload);
```

Review [Илья Зеленько's original post here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53307588/17210281)