# How can I use react-beforeunload hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, onbeforeunload, lib

The logout function should be executed only when the window is closed.
How can I differentiate between `refresh` and `close` when using `react-beforeunload` hook?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Identifying Between Refresh And Close Browser Actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568977/identifying-between-refresh-and-close-browser-actions)

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

Like the documentation says, it "listens to the `beforeunload` window event". As the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event) states

> The beforeunload event is fired when the window, the document and its resources are about to be unloaded. The document is still visible and the event is still cancelable at this point.

Both closing the tab/browser AND page refresh trigger that event, so you can't rely on that event.