# How to detect when user leaves the web page or not?

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload, unload

I want to trigger a function when the user exits the web page by closing the browser tab or pressing the browser's back button. Currently, I'm using the "beforeunload" and "unload" events. But when the user reloads the page the download event also fires. Is there a way to solve this?

```
if (performance.navigation.type == performance.navigation.TYPE_RELOAD) {} else {
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function() {
        window.addEventListener('unload', function() {
            if (!isSubmit) {
                sendDownloadEmail();
            }
        });
    });

    window.addEventListener('unload', function() {
        if (!isSubmit) {
            sendDownloadEmail();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Does his help?  [Best way to detect when a user leaves a web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/147636/1563833)

Comment: @Wyck This is not a duplicate of that question, since the OP is asking about detecting difference between close and refresh, not only to detect close

Comment: And to answer the question: No it is not possible to detect if the page is reloaded due to closing tab or refreshing. You'll have to find another way to solve your problem

Comment: OK, then does this help?  [Identifying Between Refresh And Close Browser Actions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/568977/1563833)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to capture the browser window close event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631959/how-to-capture-the-browser-window-close-event)

Answer (score -1):

1. The `beforeunload` event is used to capture tab closes and back button    presses.
2. The `pageshow` event is used to differentiate between reloads and actual page exits.
3. The `wasReloaded` flag prevents the function from firing on reloads. The `event.preventDefault()` and event.
4. `returnValue` in `beforeunload` is optional for displaying a    confirmation dialog.

```js
    let wasReloaded = false;
    
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (event) {
        if (wasReloaded) {
            return; // Skip execution if the page was reloaded
        }
    
        // Indicate that the page is about to unload
        // (can be used for confirmation dialogs or other actions)
        event.preventDefault();
        event.returnValue = 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
    
        // Trigger the function on actual page exit (not reload)
        window.addEventListener('unload', function () {
            if (!isSubmit) {
                sendDownloadEmail();
            }
        });
    });
    
    window.addEventListener('pageshow', function (event) {
        if (event.persisted) {
            wasReloaded = true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

[The best answer is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568977/identifying-between-refresh-and-close-browser-actions),and there is also a shaky answer you can test.

```js
let before_unload_time
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', () => {
  before_unload_time = new Date().getTime()
})
window.addEventListener('unload', () => {
  if (new Date().getTime() - before_unload_time >= 4) {
    localStorage.test = 'refresh:' + before_unload_time
  } else {
    localStorage.test = 'close:' + before_unload_time
  }
})
```