# Showing an alert only when a browser tab is closed, not when a page is refreshed

Tags: javascript

I want to show an alert only when I close a browser tab, not on page refresh, using JS:

```js
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        return 'Sure?';`your text`
    };

    let openedWindow;
    
    function openWindow() {
        openedWindow = window.open("moreinfo.htm");
    }
    
    function closeOpenedWindow() {
        openedWindow.close();
    }
```

I am using this code but, an alert comes on changing a page or refreshing a page.
I don't want this alert when I refresh page or change to other page.

Comment: this answer may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/13916847/14588461

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Identifying Between Refresh And Close Browser Actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568977/identifying-between-refresh-and-close-browser-actions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can add a new flag "isSwitchingPage" or something and use it like this:

```
let isSwitchingPage = false;

window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(event) {
  if (!isSwitchingPage) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.returnValue = 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
  }
});

// This is an example assuming `a` anchor is used to navigate to other pages...
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.tagName === 'A') {
    isSwitchingPage = true;
  }
});

window.addEventListener('unload', function() {
  // Reset the flag when the user leaves the page
  isSwitchingPage = false;
});
```