# Alert when close page/window

Tags: javascript, php, dom-events

How can I call code when I close page/window

```
alert("its close now");
```

but not `onunload` or `onbeforeunload`, because this also call when refresh
I want to call this alert when close only.

Comment: You can't - it would be possible to cause major annoyances for users if you could do this. And you can't tell apart a refresh from a window close within the browser, either.

Comment: I want to call alert when user click [x] or press alt+F4 , but not when refresh the page

Comment: @beginnerphp - Did you get the point? You could not tell if it is refreshing or closing.

Comment: I want to know when user open the page and when close it, and how long stay in the page, its not matter how many times refresh the page

Comment: @beginnerphp - See update in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> but not onunload or onbeforeunload , cause this also call when refresh
>   I want to call this alert when close only

When you Refresh, the current page is essentially closed and re-opened causing the `onunload` and `onbeforeunload` events to fire. AFAIK, you can't avoid that when users *refresh* the page.

Comment: I want to call alert when user click [x] or press alt+F4 , but not when refresh the page

Comment: @beginnerphp: As I told the reason, you cant tell if user refreshed the page or closed it.

Comment: I want to know when user open the page and when close it, and how long  stay in the page, its not matter how many times refresh the page

Answer (score 0):

Here is a note for you:

```
Refresh = Closing window and reopening it
```

So you will have to use `onbeforeunload`, because it is impossible to tell the user has refreshed or closed the window.

### UPDATE

Based on your comment:

> I want to know when user open the page and when close it, and how long stay in the page, its not matter how many times refresh the page.

This might be what you expected:

```
localStorage["t"] || (localStorage["t"] = 0);
var start = new Date();
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    localStorage["t"] = +localStorage["t"] + (new Date() - start);
}
```

The time the user stayed in the page is stored in `localStorage["t"]`, and updated every time he leaves. But because it is impossible to tell when the user closed the page, so you will have to set up a time interval. For example, reset it to `0` after 24 hours.

Comment: but I dont want to store when user refresh the page

Comment: @beginnerphp - Looks like you still don't get the point. **It is not possible to tell apart a refresh from a close.**

Comment: I can use session to check if refresh , but how I can know if click [x] or press alt+F4

Comment: @beginnerphp - **It is not possible to tell apart a refresh from a close.**

Comment: I must find way , I want to know when user open the page and when close it , and how long stay

Comment: `var start = new Date();window.onbeforeunload = function(){alert(new Date()-start);}`

Comment: is there an action or event happen when user close the page/window ?

Comment: Look: [To detect if the user is closing the browser apart from onunload event, as it is triggerred when user does refresh etc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181189/to-detect-if-the-user-is-closing-the-ie-browser-apart-from-onunload-event-as-it)

Comment: I don't know what are you talking about.