# How to Fire Angularjs Event when close browser or window?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to clear local storage values when user close browser or window tab using in angularjs. I tried the following code.

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
        var confirmationMessage = "\o/";
        alert("exit");
        (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage; //Gecko + IE
        return confirmationMessage;                            //Webkit, Safari, Chrome
    });
```

In the above code it asks the confirmation alert messages when refresh the page and also close the page. But i want to fire angularjs event when close the browser/Window Tab only no need to ask the confirmation messages.

Answer (score 7):

In the last project I worked on, I used the following code:

```
$window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
    if (self.form.$dirty) {
        return 'You have made changes, but you did not save them yet.\nLeaving the page will revert all changes.';
    }
}
```

First it performs a check to see if the data in the form has been changed. If so, when the user tries to close the window or go to another url, a popup will be shown stating that there are unsaved changes.

So in this event you have access to the controller, so all angular events should be able to fire.

Comment: I want to fire event when close the browser only not yet refresh page

Comment: It should also fire when the user closes the browser. The only exception is closing the browser via task manager and killing the process.

Answer (score 5):

This one worked for me, but you need to pay attention that the custom message doesn't work in most of the browsers, (such as chrome, IE, firefox).

```
window.onbeforeunload = () => {
     return 'Are you sure you want to leave without saving?';
}
```

This will fired when the user refresh or close the tab or window, with the browser default message.

Answer (score -1):

i have tried this code, it works for me!

```
      window.onbeforeunload = close;
                function close(){

                    // do something...
                    localStorage.clear();
                    sessionStorage.clear();
                   return null;
                }
```

Comment: if it returns null, there are no confirmation messages!

Comment: In the above code works fine but i want to event fire when user close the browser only. I n your code when refresh the web page that time also fires event

Comment: what do u mean? i refresh the wab page, it doesn't fire event!

Comment: i check in all browsers when i refresh the page that time also event will be fired.But i want to fire only close the browser time.

Comment: you can visit this page:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181189/to-detect-if-the-user-is-closing-the-ie-browser-apart-from-onunload-event-as-it